# Access protected class variable in different package without using public

Tags: java

My problem is hard for me to explain in words, so I'll just explain briefly, and hope you understand what I'm trying to say. :)

I'm trying to access a protected and final variable inside a class located in an interior package in the same project - that is, `com.example.Main` accessing `com.example.package.SomeClass.thisVarHere`. Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
package com.example;
import some.package.Here;
import another.package.Here;
static import com.example.package.InsideClass.statVar;

public class MainClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        System.out.println("Value of statVar is: " + statVar);
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
package com.example.package;
import pa.cka.ge

public class InsideClass {
    protected static String statVar = "Test variable";
}
```

When I try to access `statVar`, it tells me that since it's protected, I can't access it (as I expected). But I don't want it to set it public so anyone else can access it. Also, it *has* to be in the inner package, so inner classes won't work either. Is there even a way for me to accomplish this, or am I forced to set it as public and hope that no outside parties will access it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. :) Thank you!

Comment: public final is your best bet.  Your idea of 'inner package' is a misunderstanding of how java packages work there is no relation between com.example and com.example.package other then for your own organization

Comment: @MikeK. Ah, I understand. Now that I think about it, that makes sense. Thanks, and cheers.

Comment: is the `com.example.package` within the same project, or from outer library?

Comment: @MoshErsan The same project. I should add that. One second... EDIT: Done.

Comment: you can use `MainClass extends InsideClass` so now you have access to `statVar`

Comment: @MoshErsan, I thought of that right before I posted the question, actually. Sadly, it still gave me the error.

Comment: @kkirigaya No it doesn't throw error, am using it right now, I did a little sample to make sure before answering you, try to read about `default access modifier` it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to access it from another package, I don't think so. There is no way in Java for a class in package `P1` to say "Here's a variable that I want classes in package `P2` to have access to, but no other outside package". If you grant access to one outside package, you grant access to all of them. Maybe you can accomplish this with a getter function that looks at the stack backtrace to see what package the caller is in ... but that seems like overkill.  The answer is probably to rethink the design.

Comment: @kkirigaya Not sneaky--just changed my mind about where I wanted to put the answer.